# Transforming boolean to a CHAR(1) field with the JdbcSinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How can I best transform data from a boolean field on a topic to a CHAR(1) field in the database, with the value set to Y for true, N for false using the JdbcSinkConnector?

Comment: Write your own transform https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/